# How to print a message within a process when it gets the right from another process in erlang?

Tags: process, erlang, send, alarm, spawn

I'm all new to erlang, and i got this task:

- Write a function "setalarm(T,Message)" what starts two processes at
  the same time. After T miliseconds the first process sends a message
  to the second process, and that message will be the Message arg.

It's forbidden to use function library, only primitives (send, receive, spawn)

Comment: Can you post some code you've tried and show where it's failing?

Comment: As i wrote, i'm all new to this language, and i was searching a lot for the solution, but i couldn't find it, so i decided to put the whole task here. I already recieved a solution below, and now i also start to understand how it really works, so i'm thanksful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me as a novice useful to write more code, so I suggest such an option:

```
setalarm(T,Message)->
  S = spawn(sotest,second,[]),
  Pid = spawn(sotest,first,[S,T,Message]).

first(Pid,T,Message) ->
  receive
  after T -> Pid ! Message
  end.

second() ->
  receive
   Message -> io:format("The message is ~p~n",[Message])
  end.
```

Comment: Thank you, it's actually worked perfectly, as it supposed to!